# how to return string from AsyncTask to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have created a class and extend with AsyncTask , now i want to return me a string to another activity throw this class . its getting jsonstring from mysql mDatabase

```
enter code here  

public class GetJson  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
String  JSON_STRING;
String json_url;
public String pasString;
Activity ab;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    json_url="https://XXXXXXX.000webhostapp.com/Json_getData_Survey.php";
}

public GetJson(Activity b) {
    ab=b;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        URL url =new URL(json_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream  =httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();

        while ((JSON_STRING=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {

            stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
        }


        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        String  strings =stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        return  strings;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    pasString=result;

   // Toast.makeText(ab,pasString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // json_string1=result;
}
```

}

i just need to return string1 to my another  Activity , i have creaetd a another mehtod in GetJson class to return this string but when i display this it show nothing in it. please help

Comment: If you could post a little more code, not just the AsyncTask, that might be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at [Communication using interfaces](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) and [LocalBroadCastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its Quite simple
make an interface class as following

```
public interface ResponseListener() {
      void onResponseReceive(String data);
}
```

and add instance of this class in you GetJson class like this

```
public class GetJson  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
String  JSON_STRING;
String json_url;
public String pasString;
Activity ab;

// this is new code
ResponseListener listener;
public void setOnResponseListener(ResponseListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    json_url="https://XXXXXXX.000webhostapp.com/Json_getData_Survey.php";
}

// now add this code in onPost function

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   pasString=result;
   listener.onResponseReceive(pasString);

  // Toast.makeText(ab,pasString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  // json_string1=result;
}
```

now when you call GetJson from your activity, just simple do that;

```
GetJson json = new GetJson(Activity.this);
json.setOnResponseListener(new ResponseListener() {
       @Override
       public void onResponseReceived(String data) {
           // here you will get your response                                               
       }
});
```

hope you will understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try using activity results. You can set the return value on the one activity, and get it when that activity terminates.</s>

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: i know how to pass values from one activity to another but here the problem is am in j class.java which is not activity and i want to pass something to activity

Comment: @Abubakar Why don't you just pass it a callback or something along those lines? Also, you can get the result of an AsyncTask using [AsyncTask#get](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)